# C++ MySQL, Validation of input data

Tags: c++, mysql, database

It is a program using a database (MySQL) in C++.

1. Enter your student ID.
2. Students are checked for their presence. (If statement)
3. Enter the information if it exists, otherwise enter it again.
4. (Question)

To check if a student ID exists in an if statement,

I want to use select * from point where id = '%d';

However, you can not put database commands in an `if` statement. What should I do?

```
void sortSelect(MYSQL *con) {

    MYSQL * connection = NULL, conn;
    MYSQL_RES * sql_result;
    MYSQL_ROW sql_row;

    int hakbun, no, point, field, j;
    char query[1024];

    cout << " Enter Student ID > ";
    sprintf_s(query, "select * from point where hakbun='%d';", hakbun);
    cin >> hakbun;
    cout << endl;

    /* if ( ) { // Question 4
        }
        else { // Omitted
        }
    */
}
```

Comment: So do the database access first, and then test the result in the if-statement.

Comment: @BoPersson Since are checking the student ID and putting in the information, must do it first.